# Evenly selecting from a List based on number of groups?

Tags: c#

I have a list of colours with 20 items:

```
this.colors = new List<Color> {
    (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#DEEBF7"),
    (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#D2E1EF"),
    (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#C7D7E8"),
    (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#BCCDE0"),
    (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#B0C3D9"),
    (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#A5B9D2"),
    (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#9AAFCA"),
    (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#8FA6C3"),
    (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#839CBC"),
    (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#7892B4"),
    (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#6D88AD"),
    (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#627EA5"),
    (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#56749E"),
    (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#4B6B97"),
    (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#40618F"),
    (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#355788"),
    (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#294D81"),
    (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#1E4379"),
    (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#133972"),
    (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#08306B")
};
```

I'm passing a list into `GetColors`, ordering & group by the double value:

```
public SortedDictionary<Guid, Color> GetColors(IList<Tuple<Guid, double>> heightsAboveGroundByGuid)
{
   // Order providers by measurement height from ground
   IEnumerable<IGrouping<double, Tuple<Guid, double>>> groupedOrderedList = heightsAboveGroundByGuid.OrderBy(h => h.Item2).GroupBy(o => o.Item2);

   int numberOfGroups = groupedOrderedList.Count();

   SortedDictionary<Guid, Color> seriesColorsByGuid = new SortedDictionary<Guid, Color>();       

   int index = 0;
   foreach (IGrouping<double, Tuple<Guid, double>> item in groupedOrderedList)
   {
        if (index <= this.colors.Count() - 1)
        {
            foreach (Tuple<Guid, double> childItem in item)
            {
                seriesColorsByGuid.Add(childItem.Item1, this.colors[index]);
            }                   
        }

        index = Not sure how to implement this!;
   }

   return seriesColorsByGuid;
}
```

For example at run time the doubles being passed in are 40, 40, 40, 50 ,50, 60 ,60. I therefore have 3 groups. In this scenario I want the first group (40) to return colour at the index of 0, second group (50) index of 9 & the final group (60) index of 19 (the last colour in the list).

How do I set evenly spaced colours determine by the number of groups passed in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following situation (for 3, 4 and 5 groups):

> 0 --- x<sub>i</sub> ---19
>   0 --- x<sub>i</sub> ---x<sub>ii</sub> --- 19
>   0 --- x<sub>i</sub> ---x<sub>ii</sub> --- x<sub>iii</sub> --- 19
>   etc..

where --- are even(ish) gaps and x<sub>n</sub> are the numbers you are trying to find.

Laid out like that, it's clear that you have 2 gaps when there are 3 groups, 3 gaps when there are 4 groups and n-1 gaps when there are n groups. You can therefore divide the number of colours by one less than the number of groups and add that to your index each time. The following code should do what you're after. I've added a comment before each new line of code:

```
public SortedDictionary<Guid, Color> GetSeriesColors(IList<Tuple<Guid, double>> heightsAboveGroundByGuid)
{
    IEnumerable<IGrouping<double, Tuple<Guid, double>>> groupedOrderedList = heightsAboveGroundByGuid.OrderBy(h => h.Item2).GroupBy(o => o.Item2);

    int numberOfGroups = groupedOrderedList.Count();

    SortedDictionary<Guid, Color> seriesColorsByGuid = new SortedDictionary<Guid, Color>();

    int index = 0;

    //calculate the size of the gaps.
    float gap = (this.colors.Count() - 1) / (float)(numberofGroups - 1);
    //keep track of how many multiples of gap we need
    int gapsUsed = 1;

    foreach (IGrouping<double, Tuple<Guid, double>> item in groupedOrderedList)
    {
        if (index <= this.colors.Count() - 1)
        {
            foreach (Tuple<Guid, double> childItem in item)
            {
                seriesColorsByGuid.Add(childItem.Item1, this.colors[index]);
            }
        }
        //set the index to the gap * gapsUsed and cast it to an int
        index = (int)(gap * gapsUsed);
        //increment gaps used
        gapsUsed++;
    }

    return seriesColorsByGuid;
}
```

Comment: excellent thank you! I almost got it by setting the index a la your gap variable but I think declaring the gap & gapUsed variables makes it cleaner & easier to read

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to solve this problem is to calculate the distance between the expected colors for the groups. Hope it helps!

```
public SortedDictionary<Guid, Color> GetColors(IEnumerable<Tuple<Guid, double>> heightsAboveGroundByGuid)
{
        // Order providers by measurement height from ground
        var groups = heightsAboveGroundByGuid.OrderBy(h => h.Item2).GroupBy(x => x.Item2).ToList();

        var colorsByGuid = new SortedDictionary<Guid, Color>
        {
            [groups.First().First().Item1] = _colors.First(),
            [groups.Last().First().Item1] = _colors.Last()
        };

        if (groups.Count < 3) return colorsByGuid;

        var distance = _colors.Count / (groups.Count - 1);
        for (var step = 1; step < groups.Count - 1; step++)
        {
            var groupId = groups[step].First().Item1;
            colorsByGuid[groupId] = _colors.Skip(distance * step).First();
        }

        return colorsByGuid;
    }
```